# Bind WPF Radio Button to RadioButton within ViewModel`

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, radio-button

Basically I have a collection of radio buttons on in a User Control. I would like these to be equal to their 'counterparts' which are kept in a list within the ViewModel.

At the moment I have to bind pretty much every property of each one, to the applicable index in the ViewModel's collection of them. E.g:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="btnStatus2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=radioButtonsIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     Content="{Binding Path=StatusButtonList[1].Content, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Tag="{Binding Path=StatusButtonList[1].Tag, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Visibility="{Binding Path=StatusButtonList[1].Visibility, Mode=OneWay}"
                     GroupName="statusBtns" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
```

As you can see the View is going to be quite large if I have 10 radio buttons in my control. I'm pretty new to WPF and any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ItemsControl and set the ItemsSource property to your collection in the viewmodel.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RadioButtons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsRadioButtonChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

There are also special derived types of ItemsControl in WPF that provide additional features (scrolling, selected items, etc). ListView, ListBox, ComboBox, DataGrid, TreeView, etc are all ItemsControls that you could also use here

Comment: OK Thanks buddy. It seems like this is the best solution, however there's the challenge of fitting these items into a grid etc, since there are 10 of them. This is the part I'm hung up on. I'm thinking I could programmatically  specify the grid values ? Forgive my Friday afternoon sensibility..

Comment: An ItemsControl has an ItemsPanelTemplate property which specifies the layout of the items. By default it uses a StackPanel, so you shouldn't need to specify Grid.Column and Grid.Row on your RadioButtons anymore. The RadioButtons will just stack on top of each other